# Facebook mark notification as read using python

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, notifications

I have managed to read the unseen count of Facebook notifications, but was wondering if there is way to mark the notifications as read. I'm using the Facebook API for python. I saw a link that someone has posted in this site but it's expired.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the field: **unread=0** in order to mark a notification as read:

```
import facebook

graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token)
graph.put_object("notification_id", "", unread=0)
```

For more info you can refer to this: [**Graph API Doc for norfications**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/notification)

Let me know if there is any issue.

Comment: I tried it now, it gave me no error but the notification still appears on my facebook account as unread.

Comment: Where do you get the id value for notifications you wanna check?

Comment: I used the following commands:
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token)
        notifications = graph.get_object("me/notifications")
        print str(notifications)
notifications has the whole attributes of the notification, I just copied the ID and tried to set it as read. The code got processed with no errors but the notification stayed unread.